# Wifi cuts out after some time

Tags: debian, networking

I recently installed Debian on my laptop (after playing around with dozens of distros in VMs for a year or so), and while most everything has gone quite swimmingly I'm having some issues with my wifi.

Let me preface this question by saying that (as was expected) the wifi flat-out didn't work at all upon installation. I install the proper wifi drivers (which took WAY too long to find!) to get it up in the first place, but I'm only a half-step above no wifi at all now.

The problem is that after some time of use, the wifi will simply stop working. It'll still show as connected, it'll still show me as having full bars, but nothing actually related to the network will work - chrome gives me a "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET" error, ping gives me the typical "unknown host" error, and nothing else works.

Turning wifi off and on again fixes it temporarily - in a few minutes it breaks again. Although, flipping the physical wifi on/off switch on the computer doesn't fix it even temporarily.

There's never any issue using a wired connection, but that kind of defeats the purpose of having a laptop, no?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I expect that even the people who can will need you to specify what equipment (laptop, Wi-Fi, and router) you have.  Speaking of which, what happens when you try to access (ping or login to) your router?  What happens when you ping an IP address (try 8.8.8.8)?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it more complete.

Comment: In addition to the Wi-fi chipsets of both laptop and router, you should mention the age of both laptop and router. I've read people speculating that "low noise amplifiers" wear out when they age.  I've certainly experienced the symptoms you describe, but all of my gear is either used to hand-me-downs, so I never experienced it new.

Comment: Which exact drivers did you install?

Comment: You should at least tell us about the chipset, kernel version and the driver you used. In my case I have to use "wl" driver from broadcom via the bcmwl-kernel-source. That is a common case, because the broadcom chipsets are very common in notebooks. To get the Wifi-Connection stable, I had to upgrade to a current kernel 4.1.x and a patched driver version.

Comment: Maybe you are having issues with power management. Try to disable power management by issuing `iwconfig wlan0 power off`(replace `wlan0` with your wifi card name). If this works, is just a matter of adding to `pm-utils` or `laptop-mode` to get this fixed during reboots.